# Angular send many data from another component

Tags: angular

I wouldike to send data from another component but it does not work when I am doing this :

source.html:

```
<app-heat [value]="selectedValue" [list]="values"> </app-heat>
```

source.ts :

```
selectedValue = {
        Name: '',
        Matricule: '',
    }
    values = [{
        Name: "Container A",
        Matricule: "ABC",
    },
    {
        Name: "Container B",
        Matricule: "BCD",
    },
```

destination data for another component :

destination.html

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let v of list;let i = index" [list]="i">{{list}}<br>
```

destination.ts

```
@Input() value: string;
@Input() list: string;
```

I need to get data from values (name : Container A and Container B) on my input checkbox.

Comment: Isn't Java-related, as far as I can tell, would you mind removing the java-tag?

Comment: Can you tel, what is `listName`? Please create a stackblitz to reproduce your error.

Comment: @AmitChigadani sorry mistake... I just edited

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, and for test set your selectedValue:

```
selectedValue = {
    Name: 'Container A',
    Matricule: 'ABC',
  };
```

destination.ts:

```
@Input() value: any;
@Input() list: any[];
```

destination.html:

```
 <ng-container  *ngFor="let v of list;let i = index">
     <label [for]="i">{{v.Name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="i" [checked]="v.Name===value.Name && v.Matricule===value.Matricule" >
</ng-container >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**source.html**

```
<app-heat [value]="selectedValue" [list]="values"></app-heat>
```

**source.ts**

```
selectedValue = {
    Name: 'Container B',
    Matricule: 'BCD',
};

values = [
    {
        Name: "Container A",
        Matricule: "ABC",
    },
    {
        Name: "Container B",
        Matricule: "BCD",
    }
];
```

**destination.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let v of list">
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ v.Name }}">
  <label>{{v.Name}}</label>
</div>
```

You can show all selected checkboxes by the selected value

```
<div *ngFor="let v of list">
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ v.Name }}" [checked]="v.Name==value.Name">
  <label>{{v.Name}}</label>
</div>
```

**destination.ts**

```
  @Input() value: any;
  @Input() list: any;
```